# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined($document)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I running this function for a feedback panel... It was working before but now I am getting this error message.
I have no idea what has cause it. I have look for other having problems with this and try some solution but still nothing. I have try taking the `document` but still the same error

```
$(document).ready(function(){
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $(".panel").toggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: jQuery is not loaded. Check your `<script>` tag (if it really exists and/or its location).

Comment: Looks like the jQuery library isn't loaded when this code executes.  Either 1) jQuery isn't loading at all or 2) jQuery is being loaded later in the document than this code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using object and function from `jquery` library. Make sure that `jquery` script is included in your page, using any developer tool, i.e. Firebug, DragonFly, Chrome Dev tool etc.